# How to squash migrations in Flyway?

Tags: java, flyway

We have been using Flyway in our production environment since launch, it works great. But we now have dozens of migration scripts in our classpath.

How do we squash them gracefully without disturbing our production app?

Comment: Could you please describe what you would like to achieve more specifically? Are you looking to reduce your migration scripts, eliminate them, something else?

Comment: squash as in? Concatenate them into one file? Create one equivalent script that creates the final schema without going through each modification?

Comment: I'd like to be able to remove all the migration scripts and baseline against the production db as it is. Is that not a typical operation?

Comment: No it isn't a typical operation.  Normal practice is to leave the scripts etc there for future reference, and just in case they are needed.  They typically won't be applied again ... but suppose that you needed to restore an old database backup.